# Will delayed-ack acknowledge more than two packets at once time？

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

Delayed ack is used in Linux TCP implementation to reduce the number of pure ack packets by waiting for a while and aggregating the data received by receiver into a single ack packet.

According to the RFC, the delayed ack has a maximal number of **2** MSS, which means every two packets the receiver will respond an delayed ack.

I wonder to know if it's true in real Linux implementation, and is there any other ack aggregation mechanism that will compress more acks. In other words, if I have an ack packet that acknowledge more than 2 packets, it's because of some loss of acks due to network issues or some special aggregations by someone?

Thanks a lot.